# Unity Not creating a second tower

Tags: unity-game-engine

my problem is the following one.

I am creating a tower defence game, and I want to add the option to place 2 different types of towers (tower 1 with more dmg and tower 2 less dmg, for example)

Here is the code I am using:

TowerSpot.cs

```
private bool placeTower() { return tower == null;     } //Method to check if where we want to place the tower is empty or not.

public void OnMouseUp()
        {
            if (placeTower())
            {
                prefabTower =GameObject.FindObjectOfType<TowerSelection().towerType;

                gold = GameManager.Manager.getGold();

                if (gold > 0)
                {
                     //ERRROR HEREEEEEEEEEEE
                    ***tower = (GameObject)Instantiate( prefabTower , this.transform.position, this.transform.rotation);***

                    //Test code here
                    GameManager.Manager.currentGold(-20);
                }
                else
                {
                    Debug.Log("No hay suficiente dinero");
                }

            }

        }
```

As you can see there, everytime I touch the ground where I can add towers, this method "OnMouseUp" is called and a tower should be added.

Here is the code from "TowerSelection":

public GameObject towerType;

```
void Start()  {}

    void Update() {
    }

    public void TowerType (GameObject prefab) {
        towerType = prefab;
    }
```

I add the prefab using the inspector as you can see in the following photo.

[Here is the image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BjBGq.png)

As you can see in the photo, using OnClick in the right part I add the prefab of my first tower to the method "TowerType" and to my first button "Torre 1", so everytime I click the button of one of each towers the prefab should be charged using TowerType method directly in the inspector.

Then using the OnMouseUp TowerSpot.cs method and Instantiating it, the expected behavior inst working, the error I am getting is the following one:

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
TowerSpot.OnMouseUp () (at Assets/Scripts/TowerSpot.cs:25)
```

I think it's because it isn't loading the prefab from the inspector in the OnClick part of the photo I post here.

If you have any idea, I hope you can help me (in 20/30 min I'm back)

Comment: On what line you are getting the error?

Comment: tower = (GameObject)Instantiate( prefabTower , this.transform.position, this.transform.rotation);                                                                           The problem I think is "prefabTower" because it isn't loading properly the prefab from the OnClick in the inspector.

Comment: On Button Click you are just assigning the gameObject reference. You should write all the instantiation code within the TowerType method. And use Mouse Position in instantiate method

Comment: Where is your placeTower() code?

Comment: private bool placeTower()
    {
        return tower == null;
    } It's just to know if where when want to place the tower is empty or not.

Comment: can you please update your question with all the required information. So others can understand it better.